# How to align horizontally list if there is a sublist css

Tags: html, css

How to align horizontally list if there is a sublist.
menu_item (Home News ...) should to be on one line, below should to be menu_sub-item

HTML

```
        <body>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul class="menu_list">
            <li class="menu_item">
              <a href="#" class="menu_link">Home</a>
             <ul class="menu_sub-list">
                <li class="menu_sub-item"><a href="#" class="menu_sub-link">About us</a></li>
                <li class="menu_sub-item"><a href="#" class="menu_sub-link">Managment</a></li>
                <li class="menu_sub-item"><a href="#" class="menu_sub-link">History</a></li>
                <li class="menu_sub-item"><a href="#" class="menu_sub-link">Code of ethics</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">News</a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">For private
clients</a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">For corporate
clients</a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Promo campaigns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </body>
```

CSS

```
li .menu_sub-item {
      display: inline-block;
    }

.menu_item {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Unclear as to how do you want it to look. setting .menu_item to display:block is not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the horizontal list items should have `display: inline-block`,  the sub-menu items remain `block` elements, plus the `ul` of the sub-menu list should have `position: absolute` to keep it out of the flow of the horizontal list:

```
li .menu_sub-item {
  display: block;
}

ul.menu_sub-list {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzbYJZ